# What the set $I$ of invertible elements in $\mathbb{Z}_{9}$?

Tags: arithmetic

$5.2 = 1$

The set of invertible elements in $\mathbb{Z}_{9}$ is $I = \{1,2,5\}$.

Q1: Is it correct?

I was also asked to show that it is not isomorphic to $S_{3}$

How can I show that it is not isomorphic? Thank you.

Comment: When did $10$ become an element of $\Bbb Z_9$?

Comment: @DHMO I have just edited. Is it correct? Thank you.

Comment: @DHMO. What about now? Is it correct? Thank you.

Comment: Cf. my answer below.

Comment: @DHMO Thank you so much for your help sir.

Comment: Is the question $\Bbb{Z}_9$ not isomorphic to $\mathcal{S}_3$ or is it the multiplicative group of the invertible elements $\Bbb{Z}_9^{\times}$ that has six elements?

Comment: @DHMO sorry a copy paste issue.

Comment: @marwalix Sorry Marwalix for answering your question late. The multiplicative group of the invertible elements is not isomorphic to $S_3$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{array}{c|c}
\times&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\\hline
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\\hline
1&0&\color{red}1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\\hline
2&0&2&4&6&8&\color{red}1&3&5&7\\\hline
3&0&3&6&0&3&6&0&3&6\\\hline
4&0&4&8&3&7&2&6&\color{red}1&5\\\hline
5&0&5&\color{red}1&6&2&7&3&8&4\\\hline
6&0&6&3&0&6&3&0&6&3\\\hline
7&0&7&5&3&\color{red}1&8&6&4&2\\\hline
8&0&8&7&6&5&4&3&2&\color{red}1
\end{array}$$

Therefore, the invertible elements of $\Bbb Z_9$ are $\{1,2,4,5,7,8\}$.

Indeed, $S_3$ has $6$ elements while $\Bbb Z_9$ has $9$ elements, so they are not isomorphic to each other.

---

In general, for $\Bbb Z_n$, $x$ is invertible iff $\gcd(x,n)=1$.

By [Bézout's Lemma](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_Lemma), $\gcd(x,n)=1 \iff \exists a,b:ax+bn=1 \iff \exists a:ax=1$.

Comment: I think you mean $4, 7$ from your table?

Comment: @q.Then Thanks, corrected

Comment: @marwalix Ask the OP, not me.

Comment: It's also probably worth noting somewhere that in general, the units in  $\mathbb Z_n$ will be those elements $x$ such that gcd$(x,n)$=1. That is, precisely those elements coprime with the order $n$.

Comment: @kholli Is it better now?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are correct. Clearly two groups that are not the same order cannot be isomorphic to each other...

We wish to find all elements that have a multiplicative inverse in $\mathbb{Z}_9$ (as indicated by your question). 9 is not prime, so some inverses may not exist, luckily for you, $\mathbb{Z}_9$ is a relatively small group to check.
$$1, 2\cdot5, 4 \cdot 7, 8 \cdot 8$$

Those are the multiplicative inverse pairings